# Finding demand functions for an unusual utility function

Tags: microeconomics, utility, consumer-theory, demand

I have a utility function: $U = x + \min\{x,y\}$

I want to draw the indifference curve and find the demand functions. Will it be the case of the usual perfect complements?

Also, what preferences could such a utility function represent?

Will the optimal solution be at the kink?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume you know how does $\min\{x,y\}$ look like? In order to draw utility function of interest, you need to consider cases: $u(x,y)=x+\min\{x,y\}=\begin{cases}2x, \;\; \mathrm{for} \;\; x \leq y \\ x+y, \;\; \mathrm{for} \;\; x > y\end{cases}$

With $x$ on horizontal and $y$ on vertical axis:

[image]

Not sure about the "usual" perfect complements. It is more like a combination of substitutes (below $y=x$) and complements (above $y=x$).

Also, take a look here: [Identifying utility function](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/32140/identifying-utility-function/32165#32165) and [Algebraic approach towards convexity](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/32309/algebraic-approach-towards-convexity/32311#32311) where you can see more graphs.

**EDIT.**

As for the demand function, [Finding demand function given a utility min(x,y) function](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/2969/finding-demand-function-given-a-utility-minx-y-function).

Comment: Lovely answer. What tool or tools did you use to make this figure?

Comment: Thank you! I used Geogebra

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Will the optimal bundle always lie at the kink?

Answer (score 4):

To provide some real world(ish) interpretation, you could consider the following:

Wallace enjoys eating cheese on its own. He doesn't much care for crackers on their own, but he especially loves eating crackers and cheese together, he makes nice little cracker n cheese sandwiches.

In this example, we can think of cheese (x) and crackers (y) as perfect complements, but cheese will be a perfect substitute for a cracker and cheese sandwich.

If a unit of cheese is cheaper than a unit of crackers he'll skip the sandwiches and spend his whole budget on cheese, but if crackers are cheaper he'll buy cheese and crackers in equal proportions.